# Date Rendering Problem on Front-end with Different Time Zones

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I am facing a problem in rendering dates within my web app of a bank when there are differences in time zones. The backend provides the dates in the correct format, but during the rendering on the front end, discrepancies are found, especially when the time zone is different from that of Rome (UTC+2).

Details:

I use React for my web app.
Dates are provided by the backend in the UTC format: "2021-04-01T00:00:00.000+02:00".
I implemented the dateformat function using the Moment.js library to format dates.
I have noticed that the problem arises when the time difference is more than two hours compared to Rome.

Code:

```
export const placeholderForNullOrUndefined = '-';

export const dateFormat = (value?: any) => {
  console.log('Real value:', value)
  if (!value) {
    return placeholderForNullOrUndefined;
  }

  const DATE_FORMAT = "DD/MM/YYYY";

  if (!(value instanceof Date)) {
    return moment(value).format(DATE_FORMAT);
  }

  console.log('value', value);

  const data = value;
  const stringDate = value;
  const momentValue = moment(stringDate);
  const timezone = data.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
  console.log('timezone', timezone);

  return momentValue.utc(true).format(DATE_FORMAT);
};
```

Additional Questions:

How can I ensure that dates are rendered correctly regardless of time zone?
Are there any adjustments I can make to the dateformat function to better handle differences in time zones?
Thank you so much for your help!

I expect the dates to be equal
both front and back end

Comment: _"I have noticed that the problem arises "_ Please be specific about this problem, we need details. What are you seeing vs what do you expect to see? Include as much debugging info as you think is relevant. Preferably include a [mcve]

Comment: Date Times & locale can be a bit confusing.  But UTC is universal (the first letter U), the back end / front end makes no difference.  eg. the date you supplied equals -> `2021-03-31T22:00:00.000Z` in UTC, it doesn't matter were somebody is in the world, that time is constant.  How it's displayed is the real question, you should not need to be worrying about timezone offset or anything like that.

Comment: To be more specific, are you wanting that UTC time to always show Rome / Italy time no matter what the users locale is?

Comment: I see a different date on front end than the back end, so I expect the date to return the back end and the moment I am in a different time zone to the front end is wrong 

Example date returned to back-end: 2021-04-01T00:00:00.000+02:00
printed date at front-end with different time zone: 31/03/2021

Comment: I'm still not getting your problem here, of course it will be a different time in a different time zone, that's the whole point of time zones.  That's why I ask are you wanting the time at the client end to always show Rome time?  If so then using the UTC time you supplied -> `moment('2021-04-01T00:00:00.000+02:00').tz('Europe/Rome').format('DD/MM/YYYY')`  will give you `01/04/2021`

Comment: I care that in any time zone I am always returns me and anyway the date provided by the back-end service, this thing happens to me only when the time zone set on the pc to do the test is unless

Comment: I'll repeat, a UTC time is universal.  It's going to be the same time no matter what time zone you use it.  eg. a UTC time of `2024-01-24T11:41:40.626Z` in the UK -> `moment('2024-01-21T10:00:00.0Z').format('DD/MM/YYYY ha')` is -> `21/01/2024 10am`,  UK currently UTC is the same as GMT.  But in Rome `moment('2024-01-21T10:00:00.0Z').tz('Europe/Rome').format('DD/MM/YYYY ha')` it's `21/01/2024 11am`  but in both case the UTC time are identical.  This part is important, just keep all dates UTC, and how you display is all you change.

Comment: how could it change my code with your solution?

Comment: If I'm understanding your issue, just change `moment.utc` to `moment.tz('Europe/Rome')`,  `.utc` is meant for just dealing with UTC, as such time zones are totally ignored, remember `'2021-04-01T00:00:00.000+02:00'` is actually `2021-03-31T22:00:00.000Z` as UTC time when normalised.

Comment: @Keith I solved by making this change: `export const dateFormatMovimenti = (value?: any) => {
  if (value instanceof Date) {
    return moment(value).utcOffset("+0200").format("DD/MM/YYYY");
  } else return placeholderForNullOrUndefined;
};`

Comment: @matteo  That will work until Daylight saving changes.

Comment: @Keith and to manage daylight savings time as you could do